# How to get a value on a pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am an absolute beginner in Laravel.

I would like to get `"role_id"` on the pivot table or `"admin"`, but I don't know how. I would like to make a system that shows a different interface based on what role the user has. So I would like to distinguish users from `admin`, `instructor`, and `user` by getting `"role_id"` on the pivot table.

Any advice would be appreciated.

**Users.php**

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

**Roles.php**

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Role table:**

```
1|admin|2016-04-02 16:51:25|2016-04-02 16:51:25
2|instructor|2016-04-02 16:51:25|2016-04-02 16:51:25
3|student|2016-04-02 16:51:25|2016-04-02 16:51:25
```

I would like to get `role_id` on the pivot table.
I can get the table below with the code "\Auth::User()->roles"

```
{
"id": "1",
"name": "admin",
"created_at": "2016-04-02 16:51:25",
"updated_at": "2016-04-02 16:51:25",

 "pivot": {
     "user_id": "1",
     "role_id": "1",
     "created_at": "2016-04-02 16:54:06",
     "updated_at": "2016-04-02 16:54:06"
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok let me check it and get back to you shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at my roles setup, you need to add the following code after your code in `Roles.php`

```
public function hasRole($name)
{
    foreach ($this->roles as $role)
    {
        if ($role->name == $name) return true;
    } 
    return false;
}

public function assignRole($role)
{
    return $this->roles()->attach($role);
}

public function removeRole($role)
{
    return $this->roles()->detach($role);
}
```

`hasRole` checks the roles, `assignRole` and `removeRole` to add and delete roles.

For testing you can do something like

```
if ($user->hasRole('student')) return "you are in student group"
```

Comment: I made a few changes in your code and everything works as hoped. Thank you very much, Maytham!